# Unable to refresh jtextarea after Selection from JOptionPane drop down list box

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, joptionpane, jcheckbox

The first time I select an option from the list, the value is displayed on the jtextarea
The second time I select an option, the value doesn't change. 
Is there a refresh option? Or a better approach for this problem? Thanks!

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
String[] choices = {"Apple","Orange", "Pear"}; 

String fruit= (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select Fruit:","Select Fruit", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);  

if (fruit!= null){

jtextarea.append("Name\t:  " + fruit.getName() + "\n"); 
jtextarea.append("Color\t:  " + fruit.getColor() + "\n");

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

```
fruit.getName()
fruit.getColor()
```

These two are wrong since it's a refrence to what your JOptionPane returns and not an object with an getter. As it is not your array `choices` contains strings. Simply append what your joptionpane returns which is `fruit`(This will be either Apple, Orange or Pear) :

```
jtextarea.append("Name\t:  " + fruit + "\n");
```

Comment: If he wants to do it the way he's got it set up, he could also use a small inner class 'fruit' and populate the JOptionPane with three fruit objects.

Comment: I am able to get the values from my Fruit. But when I try the 2nd time, the value doesn't refresh.